# Estimating Parameters of truncated generalized pareto distribution by probability weighted moments

Tags: distributions, fitting

Is it possible to estimate parameters for a truncated Generalized Pareto Distribution ([Wikipedia Article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_Pareto_distribution)) by probability weighted moments? If not, why is that so?

I am aware that it would be possible numerically by MLE or similar methods, but I am specifically interested in whether a PWM approach is feasible.